# Sowing Once into Each of Many Lists – Any Better than Append?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, recursion, code-review, sow-reap

### In general

I know to try to use Reap and Sow over Append or AppendTo due to superior performance. However, Reap and Sow are notorious for being difficult to understand how to use and how they work behind the scenes. They really shine when you want to successively accumulate many elements in a list. However, ***is there any boost in performance in cases where you want to sow/append once into each of many lists?***

I know Reap and Sow are good for "vertical" accumulation in relatively few lists. But as the total number of things being sowed approaches the number of things being sowed onto, I expect performance to decrease. If there are as many tags as there are lists (which seems to be what is needed), and there's only one sowing for each list, I don't see how there can be a performance increase over Append, in theory.

### In particular

I ask in general, if there is an answer, but I am also looking at optimizing a particular program.

Let `list` be a list of pairs and let `pair` be a pair. If `pair` shares no element with any pair in `list`, append `pair` to the end of `list`. Else, output `Nothing`.

For example, if `list={{18, 2}, {4, 20}, {12, 19}, {6, 15}, {18, 2}}` and `pair={9, 2}`, then the output is `Nothing` because the 2 appears in some pair in `list` and in `pair`. But if `pair={5, 3}`, then the output is `{{18, 2}, {4, 20}, {12, 19}, {6, 15}, {18, 2}, {5, 3}}` because no element in `pair` is shared with any element in any pair in `list`. The following accomplishes this.

```
If[DisjointQ[Flatten[list], pair], Append[list, pair], Nothing]
```

Now, I want to do this with a collection of lists of pairs `collectionOfListsOfPairs` and a list of pairs `listOfPairs`, whereby the comparison above is performed between every list of pairs in the collection and every pair in the list. I have a program which accomplishes this.

```
Table[If[DisjointQ[Flatten[list], pair], Append[list, pair], 
  Nothing],
 {list, collectionOfListsOfPairs}, {pair, listOfPairs}]
```

So given

```
collectionOfListsOfPairs = 
{{{18, 2}, {4, 20}, {12, 19}, {6, 15}, {18, 2}}, 
{{7, 9}, {19, 3}, {16, 8}, {11, 12}, {13, 8}}, 
{{16, 8}, {4, 5}, {8, 8}, {4, 5}, {4, 10}}};

listOfPairs = {{9, 2}, {5, 3}, {15, 13}};
```

my program outputs

```
{{{{18, 2}, {4, 20}, {12, 19}, {6, 15}, {18, 2}, {5, 3}}}, {}, {{{16, 
    8}, {4, 5}, {8, 8}, {4, 5}, {4, 10}, {9, 2}}, {{16, 8}, {4, 
    5}, {8, 8}, {4, 5}, {4, 10}, {15, 13}}}}
```

***Would using Reap and Sow give better performance than than Append? If so, how would I be able to accomplish this?*** I am having trouble because I understand how Sow can build lists, but it is more difficult for me to see how Sow can add on to already given lists.

***Are there other paradigms available to optimize my program?***

Comment: hmmm...are you given `collectionOfListsOfPairs` to begin with, or are you constructing it from scratch and we just don't see it here? if you're given it, your problem might not really be amenable to `Sow` and `Reap`. However, in any case, your code might be amenable to more functional/built-in improvements, like mapping (`/@`) and `Select`, though whether this would actually increase performance or not would need to be tested!

Comment: Your thoughts are the same as mine. I can probably uncomfortably tweak things to make `collectionOfListsOfPairs` using `Sow` from scratch, but I'm wondering if it is worth it. Even if I could, if there's no performance increase over `Append` in sowing once into each of many lists (the fundamental question), then there's no point in trying.

Comment: I think it also depends on whether your construction process happens at the same-ish point in time as this appending process, or if this is a "separate" process done to `collectionOfListsOfPairs`. If the latter, I think it would be hard to make it nice. If the former, though, `Sow`ing each pair with a tag(s) corresponding to which list(s) of pairs it should be included in, and constructing `collectionOfListsOfPairs` that way from the get-go, might help. It's hard to say without the rest of the code, though—and sometimes performance surprises you even when some paradigm "should" be faster!

Comment: Even in the former case, if there are as many tags as there are lists (which seems to be what is needed), and there's only one sowing for each list, I don't see how there can be a performance increase, in theory. From what little I know of Reap and Sow, they are good for "vertical" accumulation in few lists. But as the number of things being sowed gets closer to the number of things being sowed onto, I would expect performance to decrease.

Comment: Well, in the former case, I'm imagining that you're constructing `collectionOfListsOfPairs` in the first place by `Sow`ing, so there could indeed be a "vertical" accumulation as you `Sow`ed each element of those lists in `collectionOfListsOfPairs` to construct them. but if not, then my guess would be what you said: no performance increase.

Comment: It seems using two `MemberQ` is faster than `DisjointQ` and sometimes `ContainsAny` for your case, `Table[With[{l = Flatten[list], p1 = First@pair, p2 = Last@pair}, If[MemberQ[l, p1] || MemberQ[l, p2], Nothing, Append[list, pair]]], {list, collectionOfListsOfPairs}, {pair, listOfPairs}]`

Comment: @BenIzd I see why you defined `l` using `With`, but what performance advantage do you think defining `p1` and `p2` using `With` would have? Each element of `pair` is called only once for the conditional anyways.

Comment: Is your data always rectangular arrays of machine integers? If so, sometimes figuring out a packed-array approach can be efficient. (Just a general remark.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, but thank you for the remark nonetheless.

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan it was a mistake. You're right, it doesn't have any advantage.

Comment: @BenIzd Your idea to use `MemberQ` though gave a surprising increase in performance. Do you know why that is? Do you believe will be a good strategy in general in place of `DisjointQ[list1,list2]` when one of the lists is much smaller than the other?